# Unable to create a single user using Ansible

Tags: authentication, ansible

Im trying to run the simplest Ansible script ever. But I cant as I am having the below error :

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
      - name: Create single user
        user: name="matias" password="secret" shell="/bin/bash"
```

Error :

```
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match
'all'

ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>

The error appears to be in 'matias/tasks/main.yml': line 3, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

# Example playbook that shows how to create users from the generated ansible variable file
- hosts: all
  ^ here
```

My command :

```
ansible-playbook mainplaybook.yml
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If I take your example and paste it into a file, it Just Works. I note from the error message that the example you show in the first part of your question doesn't appear to exactly match what's in your playbook, so maybe paste the exact contents of the playbook into your question.

Comment: Could you please share your inventory file too?. I think its issue with your inventory file where ansible is unable to get it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you didn't mention any hostnames on /etc/ansible/hosts directory.  You can save your hosts in /etc/ansible/hosts. Ansible looks there as a default location.